# If statement code not reaching either branch

Tags: python

> 2 people ask for a 1,000,000 loan, one who has  good credit only has to pay a 10% deposit, the other with  bad credit has to pay  a 20% deposit.

I thought, couldn't I make this from an input  statement? It asks the input questions (where I then respond good) and  then it states "process finished with exit code 0" which I guess means that there is nothing for Python to code. Here is what I've done, what I want to happen is if you type "good" then the answer will = 10,000 but if you type "bad" then you will be given the answer 20,000.

```
price = 1000000

prompt1 = input('What is  your credit rating, good or bad')

if prompt1=='Good':

    print(1000000 * 0.1)

elif prompt1 == 'Bad':

    print(1000000 * 0.2)
```

Comment: I think if you debug your code, and find out what is the result of input command, you will get your answer! For sake of community health, i would recommend to search and try different thing before posting questions otherwise you face negative feedback. I would mark your question to be reviewed by yourself and gets fixed or narrow down to specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited from what Tamerjar suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPMSs.jpg)

The reason you are not able to run this code, is that the words taken from the input statement do not match the function.

So you can change the format of your code as below
I'm using the ".lower()" function in order to take the input data and transform it to be all small letters. Please let me know if this answers your question.

```
price = 1000000

prompt1 = input('What is  your credit rating, good or bad')
prompt = prompt1.lower()

if prompt=='good':

    print(price * 0.1)

elif prompt == 'bad':

    print(price * 0.2)
else:
    print("Wrong input word")
```

I added this else statement just in case a wrong word was typed into the input. In order to handle those kinds of errors.

Comment: Seems like `price` variable is useless... :)

Comment: Hey that didn't work? It comes up with  the elif statement each time I type good/bad

Comment: Hey, not sure why that is happening, but I've tested it multiple times and it seems to be working fine. Please make sure to type the word individually. Could you please show me the full code you are using?

Comment: Sure, ill edit above and add an image! Hope  this helps :)

Comment: Its  a hyperlink  called "Edited from what Tamerjar suggested"  which will take  you to the image

Comment: @Tom, just seen the image and quite weird that its not working, i would like to suggest a few fixes, firstly could you maybe try to run the file from cmd or terminal, rather than pycharms built in terminal? Next, if that does not work, could you try running the code in a different file? And also please make sure the "prompt1" variable is not being used anywhere else.

Comment: @Tamerjar thanks for your response, I don't know how to do it  anywhere else sorry, im so bad I  know! It tried a different file and that didn't  work either. Prompt1 is not being used anywhere either.

Comment: Do you have any  more idea why not working? I have  a Mac btw.

Comment: Okay, so what you can do is open up your terminal, and type in cd (Your project directory). You can find how to cd to your project directory by searching on google. Once you are in your project directory you can the type python (your files name). in my case the file name was “test.py” so to run the file on the terminal you can type python test.py that’s in my case. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work, but it still said the else: statement, and if I remove that it writes nothing. (Was done in IDLE.) Very  confused  why its not working

Comment: Welcome to programming xD. Most of us have no clue what’s going on... So the output works correctly when the else statement was removed?

Comment: No lmao, must have not made clear, this is so frustrating, and I agree is programming  haha just a lot of Command + V. So when I  remove the else: statement there is no answer after I type good/bad. It just ends :( idk why but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That’s really weird. Can you confirm what version of python you are working with? You can do so my typing python —version in the IDE of py charm or the terminal. Make sure you are using the latest version of python. Make sure you are not using older versions of python like (2.0)

Comment: @tamerjar OMG I FIGURED IT OUT. AHAHA was a stupid mistake. I forgot to put a space after 'bad' (see below)
prompt1 = input('What is  your credit rating, good or bad ') What this meant was I had to write next to the question like this: What is  your credit rating, good or bad?Good

I fixed it so now it works! Your  code was perfect, thanks <3

Comment: Ahahhaha, these are the kind of mistakes that keep programmers molding for hours. Happy you found a way! And happy to help as well. Have a great one!